# You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, zend-framework2, composer-php

I wanted to install Zend Framework 2. So I downloaded the skeleton application. As mentioned in the ZF2 manual, we have to issue the command

```sh
php composer.phar install
```

Inside the skeleton.

But I'm getting an error

> You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https

Then I enabled the ssl_module in my wamp, I checked the php_ini file and I can see the following line

> extension=php_openssl.dll

Still I'm getting the same error. Anybody having any clue what I missed out?

Comment: I had this problem running travis-ci and it turned out that unlike every linux distro under the sun, some of the older travis-ci environments were compiled without openssl, just in case anyone else comes across the same problem.

Comment: @Kzqai is it possible to compile this extension in travis, such as for PHP 5.3.3 in [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38427977/4233593)? I see from [their cookbook](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php/#Installing-additional-PHP-extensions) that you can install PECL extensions, but I don't think the openssl extension is available through PECL.

Answer (score 291):

PHP CLI SAPI is using different `php.ini` than CGI or Apache module.

Find line `;extension=php_openssl.dll` in `wamp/bin/php/php#.#.##/php.ini` 
and uncomment it by removing the semicolon (`;`) from the beginning of the line.

Comment: I also had to enable the phar extension ( extension=php_phar.dll ) and as said below, the apache ssl module !

Comment: "PHP CLI SAPI is using different php.ini than CGI or Apache module." That was the trick!

Comment: If you can't find that line in your `php.ini` just simply add the line `extension=php_openssl.dll` under the Dynamic Extensions part in it.

Comment: I am Using xampp, Composer giving the same open ssl missing error even after removing the ';' of openssl extension in php.ini.

Comment: If you are using Mac and `port`, you can select the PHP version by `port select php php55` and install the extension `port install php55-openssl`

Comment: how to edit this settings in shared hosting like godaddy

Comment: Try creating php.ini in your root folder as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140917/how-to-access-the-php-ini-file-in-godaddy-shared-hosting-linux

Answer (score 36):

Verify you are editing the correct php.ini file.

Reference:
https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1440

"WAMP uses different php.ini files in the CLI and for Apache. when you enable php_openssl through the WAMP UI, you enable it for Apache, not for the CLI.
You need to modify C:\wamp\bin\php\php-X.Y.Z\php.ini to enable it for the CLI."

Comment: who would thought that... Really... This solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 26):

make sure you have correct path to extension folder

> extension_dir = "ext"

by default it is commented with ; character

Comment: this line was commented out completely and now it works

Comment: important for windows installation!

Comment: Where is this line? In which file? the php.ini in 1, C:\wamp64\bin\apache OR 2. C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.0 ?

Comment: This saved me hours of frustration, ssl was uncommented but this ext was not. Thank youuuuuuuuu!!!!

Answer (score 11):

I also had the same issue while playing around Zend Framework 2 and composer. I'm using PHP 5.4 (installed via macports) and my solution was to install openssl for PHP 5.4 via macports as well.

```
sudo port install php54-openssl
```

Answer (score 6):

I have faced this problem, but configuging openssl (also for cli) did not help.

**I have updated composer and this sloved my problem.**

Just type:

```
$ php composer.phar self-update
```

or

```
$ composer selfupdate
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

I use XAMPP.  In C:\xampp\php\php.ini, the entry for openssl did not exist, so I added "extension=php_openssl.dll" on line 989, and composer worked.

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable "extension=php_openssl.dll" in both files (php and apache). my pc files path are these :

1. C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.ini
2. C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin\php.ini

Comment: This is wrong. Check with phpinfo() which php.ini is used

Answer (score 3):

Uttam, if your issue is not solved then try the follwoing 3 step approach. It worked for me as I had exactly same issue.

step1: click on wamp tray icon.

step2: goto menu apache->apache modules

step3: click on menu item "ssl_module"

it will automatically restart wamp. if wamp not restarted automatically then restart it through wamp tray menu-> Restart All services. After restart confirm that "ssl_module" coming as ticked under menu apache->apache modules

after that just attempt the php composer.phar install 
from going through the response shared by you, php.ini file contains extension=php_openssl.dll and the php/ext directory also have file "php_openssl.dll"

good luck

Answer (score 3):

The Valery's answer helped me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14265815/492457

> WAMP uses different php.ini files in the CLI and for Apache. when you
>   enable php_openssl through the WAMP UI, you enable it for Apache, not
>   for the CLI. You need to modify C:\wamp\bin\php\php-5.4.3\php.ini to
>   enable it for the CLI.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you update your `php.ini` for `CLI`. For my case this was `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.ini` and uncomment `extension=php_openssl.dll` line.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but adding so other can learn the reason.

You also need to edit the php.ini file in the "wamp\bin\php\php-X.Y.Z" location.

Answer (score 0):

I had to uncomment `extension=openssl` in `php.ini` file for everything to work!

Answer (score 0):

Becareful if you are using wamp don't use the wamp ui to enable the `extension=php_openssl.dll`

just go to your php directory , for example : `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12` and edit the `php.ini` and uncomment the `extension=php_openssl.dll`.

it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing this error

> "You must enable the openssl extension in your php.ini to load
> information from.."

I solved by finding and uncommenting the following lines on php.ini file

```
;extension=php_openssl 
;extension_dir = "/c:\wamp64\bin\php\php 8.0.25\ext\/"
;extension=bz2
;extension=curl
;extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=ldap
;extension=mbstring
;extension=exif
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=shmop
```

in

```
Wamp/bin/php/php 8.0.25/php.ini
```

Uncomment both by removing the semicolon (`;`) from the beginning of each line.

If you have the latest PHP v^8 or above, likely you won't see php.ini file. So what you do is to make a copy of php.ini-development which you will see there and then rename the copy you just made to php.ini and then do the same uncommenting of the two lines then save.