# How to access the php.ini file in godaddy shared hosting linux

Tags: php

I have a web, and running well on my localhost.

After I Upload on my godaddy hosting, My web got a bug. the conclusions is, I MUST change the memory_limit on the php.ini file, BUT  cant find php.ini on FTP manager.

I have tried to:

- Find the way for change to the Classing FTP manager.
- Create /  upload php.ini file from local and not work.

My Questions is : How I can Fix this? I Must change php.ini file. 
does anyone have experience like me?

Comment: Why Godaddy haven't php.ini EZConfig like other Cpanel?

Comment: check path of php.in with <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: If i am correct you can create new php.ini file inside your hosting folder.this url will help you .
http://roberto-montero.com/blog/how-tweak-you-phpini-godaddycom


http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5647/why-isnt-my-phpini-file-taking-effect

Comment: /web/conf/php5.ini  this path from PHP info

Comment: @Septiyo can you access this path?

Comment: @aneesh it Doesnt work. Any Idea??

Comment: @Fabio I cant Find this PAth....on my Godaddy FTP manager.

Comment: @Septiyo Try my solution by creating your own `php.ini` file.

Comment: @Septiyo i think this is because they don't allow to modify php.ini if you are on shared server. try Yogesh Suthar solution,

Comment: Thanks All, it resolve. my mistake is I try many times upload php5.ini but I copy from XAMPP. After I googling n try download php5.ini from godaddy. Edit it and upload it Again my web can work well. Thanks So much

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Create `php.ini` file with your desired setting and upload it in your root folder of server. It will take effect with this new setting.

You can't edit the `php.ini` file of `godaddy` server, but you can upload your own copy of your `php.ini` with your new setting.

This new setting will be available only to you. Other websites will not be affected with this new setting.

Previously I faced the same issue, but after doing this my problem was resolved.

Comment: I have try your advice, I have edit php.ini from  xampp localhost, and i upload. after that I try Login to my web & I cant Login. Can I Copy your PHP.ini? whether your php.ini from xampp too?

Comment: Hi I'll like to add that you must know what name you should put to your *.ini file, and here in the support page of godaddy comes. (I have a chat with them recently) 

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8913/what-filename-does-my-php-initialization-file-php-ini-need-to-use?locale=en

Maybe this can help future problems

Comment: @magorich thank you for that link. For managed wordpress hosting it's actually .user.ini instead of php.ini. Stupid, but it worked.

Comment: For Linux hosting plans, the file name should be `php5.ini`

Comment: can you explain how to create custome php.ini ( I want to enable extension=php_openssl.dll) extension on shared hosting i.e.Godaddy

Answer (score 23):

Procedures:

- Go to your **CPanel**
- Select **PHP version**
- Click on the link **Switch to PHP options**
- Edit your configuration
- don't forget to click **save**

[image]

You can also follow this screencast

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdUlIkZcOe0

Comment: thanks man! after 2 hours of searching and talking godaddy technical support you saved my life.

Comment: That setup is pretty horrible. I set error reporting and logging and... I looked later and it says "enter the path of your error log file"... only problem cannot specify the path. I have wasted well over an hour thinking I must be stupid looking for a log that did not exist!

Comment: @BeNice the interface might have been updated since 2017.

Comment: I eventually went with `.user.ini` which works fine. Now if only I knew what I was doing!!!

Comment: Same happened here, I was struggling for 20 mins changing the .htaccess and wp-config then found that the client is using an old PHP version lol

Answer (score 20):

As pointed out by @Jason, for most shared hosting environments, having a copy of php.ini file in your public_html directory works to override the system default settings. A great way to do this is by copying the hosting company's copy. Put this in a file, say copyini.php

```
<?php
  system("cp /path/to/php/conf/file/php.ini  /home/yourusername/public_html/php.ini");
?>
```

Get /path/to/php/conf/file/php.ini from the output of phpinfo(); in a file. Then in your ini file, make your amendments 
Delete all files created during this process (Apart from php.ini of course :-) )

Comment: I still don't understand.  Can you give an actual example please

Comment: Doesn't that need to be named copyphp.ini rather than copyini.php?

Comment: It can be named anything really; it serves to copy the php.ini file so both names are descriptive enough. The most descriptive would probably be copyphpini.php

Comment: @johnktejik, this solution boils down to one thing - add a file named php.ini (or php5.ini in some cases) to your public_html folder and make your configuration changes there. In most cases, those configs will override the webhost's PHP configurations. There are a few exceptions to this rule depending on what you are trying  to override(https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) and your webhost's setup but this is generally a good rule of thumb

Answer (score 7):

To check whether your `php.ini` file takes effect, open a plain text editor and create a file called `phpinfo.php`. Insert the following line:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Save this file to the root of your Web site and then browse to yourdomain.com/phpinfo.php to test the settings.

Comment: I've tried what you ordered, on that file I can know the path of my php.ini, and I get this:/web/conf/php5.ini. But  I can't find that on FTP file manager. Same as if I try to FIND via filezilla FTP client. Any Idea?

Comment: Thanks, This worked for me. The info is very detailed.

Comment: @Adarsh For security reason remove the phpinfo file from the root level, once you get the details. Because everyone can access this file WARNING.

Answer (score 4):

Septiyo,

You need to create your own php5.ini file and upload it to your root directory.  Using GoDaddy (as I do) you do not have control over the web/conf/ folder to make any changes to their version.  Be sure if you're using PHP5 to name your file php5.ini or php.ini for PHP4.  Upload it to your root folder, then restart your page, then check using phpinfo() to see if the directory of your php file has changed correctly.

For more information, check this link out.
http://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/phpini-file/

Comment: what is the root folder you mean ? Home?

Comment: @Wang'lPakhrin root folder is where all your wordpress files sits (wp-config.php, index.php, wp-load.php ...)

Answer (score 4):

if you don't have a good copy of your `php5.ini` file in your home directory (a predicament that I recently found myself in), you'll need to follow a little multi-step process to make your changes.

1. Create a little code snippet to look at the output of the `phpinfo()`  call. This is simple, and there are multiple web-sites that describe this process.
2. Examine the output of `phpinfo()` for the row which contains `Configuration File (php.ini) Path`. Mine was in `/usr/local/lib`, but your's may be a different path (depends on hosting level purchased).
3. GoDaddy will NOT simply copy this file into your home directory for you --as silly as that sounds! But, you can write a little php program to copy this php.ini file into your home directory. The guy at
   https://www.jabari-holder.com/blog/how-to-get-godaddys-php5-ini-file/
   has a drop-box with this code snippet, if you care to use it. Just
   take care to modify two things:

   - a. change the path you read 'from' to match the path you uncovered in Step 2.
   - b. change the output file-name to something of your    choosing.    You're going to re-name this file in a later step anyway. Let's call our copied file `Foo.ini` (but it can be anything).
4. Rename `Foo.ini` to `.user.ini` (for most GoDaddy account types).

Comment: [Here's a link to their documentation on the file name.](https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-filename-does-my-php-initialization-file-need-to-use-8913)

Comment: Also, the output file isn't "something of your choosing".  It's gotta be the same name as your current INI file.  Anyway, this is definitely the easiest way to do it.  Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 4):

Create a new **php.ini** file with your desired settings and upload it to **public_html** folder of your Godaddy Hosting Account.

By default, **Godaddy** doesn't allow to edit it's existing **php.ini** file. However, you can always upload your own copy of your php.ini file with your own settings.

Below is an example of a simple php.ini file with some custom values:

```
max_execution_time 600
memory_limit 128M
post_max_size 32M
upload_max_filesize 32M
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem with my GoDaddy account.

I am running the ***Linux hosting with cPanel***

follow these steps and you should be fine if you are running the same hosting as me:

first, go to you **Manage Your Hosting -> Manage**

then you will see a section called **Files**, click on **File Manager**

you can select the **Document Root for: yourwebsite.com** then click **GO**

this should bring you right away in the **public_html** folder

in that folder, you can **add a file (by clicking the +File in top left corner), call it phpinfo.php**

right click that new file, and select edit :

right this in it and save changes:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

it the same **public_html** folder, add another file called **php.ini**

edit this one too, right those lines:

```
max_execution_time 600
memory_limit 128M
post_max_size 32M
upload_max_filesize 32M
```

now, go back to your **Manage Your Hosting -> Manage**, look for **PHP Process**

**click Kill Process**, this will allows a refresh with your new settings. you are good to go

*side note: you can see your new settings by navigating to yourwebiste.com/phpinfo.php*

Answer (score 1):

I found a guide to reload the php5.ini file or load a new one right away. You will need to access your Godaddy hosting panel where you will find the option "system process" do a restart there and it will load the php5.ini or php.ini file right away.

2 external guides to assist you:

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5980/managing-system-processes-on-linux-hosting-accounts

http://www.studio-owens.com/blog/GoDaddy-and-Your-php-ini-File.htm

Answer (score 0):

For some hosting accounts, I'm on Ultimate Classic Linux, the file name you need to use is .user.ini.

Answer (score 0):

It's an older question, but if anyone has a problem with setting this, their documentation is outdated. I made a copy of the `php.ini` file named `php5.ini` and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below if you use godaddy shared hosting..
its very simple:
we need to access root folder of the server via ftp, create a "php5.ini" named file under public_html folder... and then add 3 stupid lines... also "php5" because I'm using php5.4 for 1 of my client. you can check your version via control panel and search php version. Adding a new file with php5.ini will not hamper anything on server end, but it will only overwrite whatever we are commanding it to do.

steps are simple: 
go to file manager..
click on public_html..
a new window will appear..
Click on "+"sign and create a new file in the name: "php5.ini" ... click ok/save. Now right click on that newly created php5.ini file and click on edit... a new window will appear... copy paste these below lines & click on save and close the window.

memory_limit = 128M

upload_max_filesize = 60M

max_input_vars = 5000

Answer (score 0):

Not php.ini file, but a way around it. Go to GoDaddy's

> Files > Backup > Restore a MySQL Database Backup

Choose your file and click Upload. No timeouts. Rename the DB if needed, and assign a user in

> Databases > MySQL Databases