# How to change max_input_vars in godaddy server without accessing php.ini file?

Tags: php

I cannot access `php.ini` file to edit `max_input_vars`.
How can I change it from my webroot? I had created php5.ini file within my root and added the following.

```
[PHP]
max_input_vars = 5000
```

But nothing happened.max_input_vars still shows its old value, `1000`.

Comment: using `ini_set`? http://au2.php.net/ini_set

Comment: I have tried it also.But not working.

Comment: After setting that, you need to restart the server

Comment: The setting isn't configurable using ini_set. You'll need to use an .htaccess or a user.ini http://au1.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Comment: Can I add user.ini file ,with content max_input_vars = 5000 ,into my webroot?,in the same way we add php.ini?

Comment: If the webserver is running PHP 5.3.0 or above and is running CGI/FastCGI then yes, if not, .htaccess would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks to all.I had got it worked by adding php5.ini and restarted my server.I dont know how to restart correctly.so I logged out several times and accessed my webroot.Finally it worked.thanks

Answer (score 2):

In GoDaddy shared hosting in Cpanel,
placing the following code by creating a new file `.user.ini` in root directory resolved the problem.

```
max_input_vars = 5000
```

Additionally, I also wanted to increase the file upload size, so, i created a `php.ini` file in `public_html` and placed following code:

```
[PHP]
file_uploads = On
post_max_size = 50M
upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

Thanks to @fyrye suggestion.

Just for clarification, putting code in `.htaccess` file to override php settings will most likely bring 500 internal server error in GoDaddy Shared Hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running as CGI and using .user.ini

http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

According to ini config settings this should work for you
http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars

> PHP_INI_PERDIR     Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or
>   .user.ini (since PHP 5.3)

You may also need to go to your hosting processes in the godaddy control panel and restart all web processes.

Also see:
[How to access the php.ini file in godaddy shared hosting linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140917/how-to-access-the-php-ini-file-in-godaddy-shared-hosting-linux)

Comment: Thanks to all.I had got it worked by adding php5.ini and restarted my server.I dont know how to restart correctly.so I logged out several times and accessed my webroot.Finally it worked.thanks

Comment: In your godaddy control panel for your hosting (click launch next to your godaddy hosting). There is a button called System Processes in the stats and monitors section. Once opened you simply click End Web or End All, and the desired server processes will end for your hosting and restart on demand. http://www.studio-owens.com/blog/GoDaddy-and-Your-php-ini-File.htm