# symfony2 application on godaddy: no input file specified

Tags: apache, symfony, php-5.4

I deployed a symfony2 application on godaddy and I got this error: no input file specified. After some research I managed to solve with some changes on .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php/ [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
```

this works but only for urls like /mycontroller, I still get errors when using urls like /mycontroller/newaction. what else can I change to manage it working?  thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good post how to fix that problem.

> When getting started with Symfony2 using Apache and fast-cgi for PHP, you may get the following message come up when trying to open up
>   the /app_dev.php/demo URL.
>
> No input file specified. This occurs because the url rewrite module isn’t passing along the pathinfo details properly to the fcgi
>   php. Here’s how you can fix it.
>
> 1.) Open the relavent php.ini file
>   2.) Look for the cgi.fix_pathinfo setting.
>   3.) You’ll most likely find it set to 0.
>   4.) Change it so that it reads cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
>   5.) Save the changes. Restart Apache.
>   6.) Try loading up /app_dev.php/demo/. It should work now.

http://wilt.isaac.su/articles/symfony2-no-input-file-specified-

Comment: I'm on a shared, I can't change php.ini. I tried already to create a php5.ini in my dir but with no success. maybe I created the file in the wrong place? where exactly can I try to put it?

Comment: You can make a phpinfo to find out which php.ini is loaded.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140917/how-to-access-the-php-ini-file-in-godaddy-shared-hosting-linux

Comment: /web/conf/php5.ini, and it is readonly for me of course. Can I override this?

Comment: yes I read it and I tried already, no luck. maybe I need to reload the conf? I don't have cPanel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74406/discussion-between-user3174311-and-stony).