# How can I access php.ini on Mac

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently trying to change settings in my php.ini file so I can increase the file size for wordpress plugins, etc. I posted a picture of the path of where it is but I am not able to get to it.

[image]

I tried cmd + space and typed ~/Library but from there have no clue what folder to select or anything. Typing the full address in finder yields no results. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running a [local server](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/tutorials/installing-a-local-server/) (like [MAMP](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_Locally_on_Your_Mac_With_MAMP))?

Comment: Hosting with GoDaddy.

Comment: Ah, then the `php.ini` file is on GoDaddy's server, not your Mac.

Comment: I'm not seeing this file locally on my machine. Is this a third party program?

Comment: I believe this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140917/how-to-access-the-php-ini-file-in-godaddy-shared-hosting-linux