# Joomla 3.6.2 Installation do not proceed at step 1

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

I am trying to install Joomla 3.6.2 on remote server, have uploaded all files through FTP (FileZilla) and now when I fill up the Main Configuration form (see image below) and click on next a loader appears for few seconds and then goes without any change.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with your max_execution_time in `php.ini` file of your server. If all other requirements of Joomla are satisfied and you are still stuck up then possibly you need to increase max execution time. For that you need to edit `php.ini` file. Editing php ini file may be possible through your control panel or you can directly open file manager and edit php.ini file. Its default is 30s and you need to increase to a bigger number. I keep it at 300s.

Note: **remember to restart apache after editing**.

EDIT:

After a long search I found this for you as I have never hosted on GoDaddy
This is the link https://www.drupal.org/node/1209090
Useful for Linux Hosting.

```
1. create a new file called ‘.user.ini’
2. place the following code inside it;

max_execution_time=300

3. upload to hosting root (public_html)
4. login to your GoDaddy control panel and navigate to ‘PHP Processes’
5. click on Kill all processes
6. clear cache
7. job done!
```

Comment: I am trying to install it on a hosting bought from GoDaddy, how can I change these settings there?

Comment: You have to create a php.ini file in your root folder. Changes take some time. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140917/how-to-access-the-php-ini-file-in-godaddy-shared-hosting-linux

Comment: I have uploaded new php5.ini file on server but still it is not working.

Comment: Try renaming to just php.ini. remove 5 from php5.

Comment: @Hanumendra I have updated my answer that can help you. Plz check.

Comment: I just did what you have mentioned in your updated answer but it is still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121540/discussion-between-amit-ray-and-hanumendra).