# joomla 3 purity 3 template i cannot upload plugin

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I am trying to upload the purity 3 template for joomla, I downloaded 4 filers from there homepage, an extention manager, this file i can upload. and T3 plugin, this i cannot upload, i recieve the following error when trying:

Error
There was an error uploading this file to the server.
Maximum PHP file upload size is too small: This is set in php.ini in both upload_max_filesize and post_max_size settings of your PHP settings (located in php.ini and/or .htaccess file).
Unable to find install package

without this plugin i cannot get the template to work, i recieve this error:

500 - T3 Plugin is not enabled

You may not be able to visit this page because of:

```
an out-of-date bookmark/favourite
a search engine that has an out-of-date listing for this site
a mistyped address
you have no access to this page
The requested resource was not found.
An error has occurred while processing your request.
```

Please try one of the following pages: Home Page

If difficulties persist, please contact the System Administrator of this site and report the error below..

T3 Plugin is not enabled

I have tried to change the .htaccess file by adding this: 
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value memory_limit 32M

I cannot find the right php.ini file.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: if you don't have php.ini in root folder you need to create it.
Please take a look at this question - in many hostings php configuration looks very simialar:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140917/how-to-access-the-php-ini-file-in-godaddy-shared-hosting-linux

Comment: Talk to your hosting provider and ask them to increase the limits that are currently set.

Comment: Yes now it works, thx.. I uploaded a phpinfo.php file to the root. as descriped