# How to resolve the error: Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection refused)

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, ssl

I'm using **codeigniter** I created one email function to send email to particular email ID

```
public function email($email){
        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_timeout']=5;
        $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'MyEmailID@gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = '********************';
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $this->email->from('MyEmailID@gmail.com', 'MyEmailID');
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject('My Subject');
        $this->email->message('My Message');
        return $this->email->send();
    }
```

That's working nice in my local machine but when I uploaded that code to **hosting server** (*I'm using **Godaddy** hosting*) I'm getting following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465
>   (Connection refused)
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 2020
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/MyDir/public_html/application/models/BasicModel.php
>   Line: 47 Function: send
>
> File: /home/MyDir/public_html/application/controllers/Login.php
>   Line: 48 Function: email
>
> File: /home/MyDir/public_html/index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Comment: try ssl://smtp.googlemail.com

Comment: above code is working with my localhost but not with my hosting :(

Comment: did you find a solution for this? Same issue here :/

Answer (score 2):

**Use Tls istead of ssl and change port number to 587**
                $this->email->initialize($config);
                $config = array();

```
     //Load email library 
        $config['protocol']    = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host']    = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_port']    = '587';
        $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
        $config['smtp_user']    = 'email';
        $config['smtp_pass']    = 'password';
        $config['charset']    = 'utf-8';
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not      



            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
            ;
            $this->email->clear(TRUE);
            $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));
            $this->email->subject($row_email->email_subject);
```

[working site](http://www.subkuchsell.com/user/forgot)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error was in my case caused by a source server firewall blocking the the SMTP connection.

It can help to unblock/whitelist destination IP or disable SMTP blocking/whitelist user in ConfigServerFirewall (if used) configuration:

```
SMTP_BLOCK = off
SMTP_ALLOWUSER = usernamehere
```

Answer (score -1):

**You forgot to add '**

change from

```
 $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
```

to

```
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
```

or

Uncomment `php_openssl.dll` in php.ini

Comment: That's not the mistake in my code I did that accidentally while typing question ..

Comment: I'm using godaddy host so where shoud I found php.ini

Comment: have you chacked with first solution?

Comment: reference how to create php.ini on godaddy server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140917/how-to-access-the-php-ini-file-in-godaddy-shared-hosting-linux

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132117/discussion-between-abhijit-kumbhar-and-dhruv-jadia).

Answer (score -1):

Change from:

```
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.seuDominio.com';
```

To:

```
$config['smtp_host'] = 'mail.seuDominio.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = 587; //587
$config['smtp_user'] = 'seu@dominio.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'suaSenha';
```

Change from:

```
$config['protocol']  = 'smtp';
```

To:

```
$config['protocol']  = 'mail';
$config['validate']  = TRUE;
$config['mailtype']  = 'html';
$config['charset']   = 'utf-8';
$config['newline']   = "\r\n";
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. The original code does not contain any occurence of `smtp.seuDominio.com`