# Php.ini is missing in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, godaddy-api

I have a site under Magento 1.9 that i want to increase the upload size to Max but the php.ini file is missing in the host file manager.

Im using goDaddy host account and I only able to locate phpsample.ini file instead. How do I increase the upload file to max?

Comment: It's not there by default. Go ahead and create it.

Comment: [how to access the php ini file in godaddy shared hosting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140917/how-to-access-the-php-ini-file-in-godaddy-shared-hosting-linux)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the php.ini file in godaddy shared hosting linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140917/how-to-access-the-php-ini-file-in-godaddy-shared-hosting-linux)

Comment: can you see `php.ini.sample` file in root of the site....

Comment: Hi..I've done create and add in the php.ini file and increase the upload size to 64M, but still when i try to upload in a file size around 3mb is state the upload max size is still 2mb

Comment: user5348fh8y5 : Yes, I can see the php.ini.sample available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally able to solve the issue. What i did was i put in phpinfo.php in the root location to check the location and source of the php.ini and amend the default php.ini that was in the control panel instead.