# Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in php 5.6

Tags: php, linux, ms-access, webserver

I have multiple MS Access database put on the Linux web server, which is hosting by GoDaddy. but when I try to login through my login portal, it gives me error: Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in /home/buerer/public_html/flames/events/checklogin.php on line 11

here is the code for checklogin.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
global $rs;
// parse username and password sent from signup form post to php variables
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 
$access = realpath("db/users.mdb");
$_SESSION['accessLevel'] = "READ DATA FROM TABLE";
//create connection as COM object
$conn = new COM('ADODB.Connection') or exit('Cannot start ADO.');
//create recordset as new COM object
$rs = new COM('ADODB.Recordset')  or exit('Cannot create recordset.');
//dim connection with driver and password
  $conn->Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=$access;Jet OLEDB:Database Password='softball1234';");
//$conn->Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=$access;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=$mypassword;");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE VendorCode='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";
//execute sql in connection to database to store are recordset
$rs = $conn->Execute($sql);


if ($rs->EOF) {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
        print "<br>Click <a href=main_login.php>here</a> to try again.";

  //print $rs->ErrorMsg(); // Displays the error message if no results could be returned
}else{
        $_SESSION['AccessLevel'] = $rs->fields["AccessLevel"]->value;
        $_SESSION['MailingListID'] = $rs->fields["MailingListID"]->value;
        $count = 0;
    while (!$rs->EOF) { 
        $count++;
        $rs->MoveNext();
     } //while !$rs->eof

    if($count>0){
        // Register $myusername, $mypassword and AccessLevel and redirect to file "selection.php"
        $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $mypassword;


        //$_SESSION['AccessLevel'] = $rs->fields["AccessLevel"]->value;

        header("location:selection.php");
    }else {

        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
        print "<br>Click <a href=main_login.php>here</a> to try again.";
        session_destroy();
        }
}
?>
```

I can not find php.ini file in my GoDaddy file manager, does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Class COM is a windows-only extension. What do you expect on nix server?

Comment: Yes, I can@webDev

Comment: Check this link for accessing php.ini file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140917/how-to-access-the-php-ini-file-in-godaddy-shared-hosting-linux

Comment: @RavinderReddy And what is the OP suppose to do in the php.ini file?

Comment: This might help you : https://gist.github.com/amirkdv/9672857

Answer (score 0):

From PHP 5.4.5, COM and DOTNET is no longer built into the php core.you have to add COM support in php.ini:

[COM_DOT_NET]
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
Otherwise you will see this in your error log: Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found

Comment: As OP added tag `linux`, I think it's his OS, so you also could mention that `COM` extension is not available on nix systems.

Comment: Do you know where I can access my php.ini file in a Linux webserver? the path on the phpinfo.ini does not exist.

Comment: In most of the case `/etc/php.ini`

Comment: @Bowen once again `COM` __will not work__ on linux servers. Do you copy?

Comment: `*.dll`-files are _Windows only_ (like @u_mulder repeatedly have said).

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks for the help