# Thing worked on localhost but no server side getting error :Internal Error 500 with PHP and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to use the prepared statement for very first time. It worked fine on localhost in postgres but now not working on website. The error is always : Internal server error 500.

Following is the code

```
$test_query = "SELECT pid, productname FROM products WHERE pid = 1";
if(isset($_POST['submission'])){
$db_connect =new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
$email = $_POST['emailid'];
if (!$db_connect) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}else{
    echo "Connected successfully : " ;
    $stmt = $db_connect->prepare($test_query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $response=$stmt->get_result();

    if($response->num_rows>0){
        print "Hurrey!";
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code working fine in both localhost and Server as well, check your database credentials. If there is no problem with database connection, then find your error by setting Error reporting ON in your server's php.ini file configuration

Comment: Anitha: How to set error reporting On?  There is successful database connection but after adding select statement it stops with 500.

Comment: use `error_reporting(-1);` in your PHP code to view any error from your code and also in your php.ini file uncomment the line "error_reporting=E_ALL" by removing (;) before the line starts

Comment: Creating new php.ini is only option on godaddy server. How could I do both tasks suggested.

Comment: Where did you have your php files?

Comment: I created the php5.ini and added the lines as suggested in this link. My all files are in public_html folder of godaddy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140917/how-to-access-the-php-ini-file-in-godaddy-shared-hosting-linux .. hope you did like this in godaddy server.