# OpenSSL error with Composer PHP package manager

Tags: php, openssl, composer-php

When I attempt to run `composer install` in the CLI, I get this error:

```
You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https
```

The problem seems to be on line 5381 of my `composer.phar` file:

```
if (!extension_loaded('openssl') && (0 === strpos($url, 'https:') || 0 === strpos($url, 'http://github.com'))) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https');
}
```

I have enabled the openssl extension in both my php.ini files. (Apache and PHP)

If I run `openssl version` in the CLI it returns

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
```

I ran the following PHP script through my WAMP server:

```
echo extension_loaded('openssl');
```

It printed `1`

As far as I can tell, my openssl extension is working fine, but for some reason it is still causing this error for Composer.

Does anyone see any problems I may have overlooked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Composer Warning: openssl extension is missing. How to enable in WAMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062055/composer-warning-openssl-extension-is-missing-how-to-enable-in-wamp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291151/you-must-enable-the-openssl-extension-to-download-files-via-https)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between PHP running inside a HTTP server, and on command line - both cases use their own configuration, so it might be that your command line version has not SSL extension configured.

Check for yourself: `php -i` shows you the phpinfo output on the command line. Any OpenSSL to be seen?

While you are at it, use the same output, locate the info on which `php.ini` is being used, and add the OpenSSL extension.

Comment: I did what you said. Openssl was disabled in one of `php.ini` files I mentioned I had enabled it in. I seriously checked it like 5 times earlier... As always, I probably just did something stupid. Anyway, even though the correct answer should have been `Don't be an idiot`, I'm going to accept yours. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As you did not provide a lot of information, I just assume that your system setup (Windows XP, WAMP) is similar to mine. In principle this answer should work on Unix but I am not able to check it.

Anyway, I had PHP running on WAMP and I had set up the ini-files correctly but still I got the same error as you did. After doing some research and a lot of tinkering, I noticed that the PHP running on command line did not actually use any ini-files (command `php --ini`). After noticing that, I got composer running properly by setting the ini-file with `php -c` command.

Long story short, try this command `php -c /path/to/ini/file composer install` and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the problem while installing Composer. I had saved the php file to c:\php. In the php.ini file I opened the extension  =php_openssl.dll  by removing the semi colon with no success. i found the extension openssl.dll in the sub directory called ext . I copied it to the c:\php directory. I met with immediate success.  What a hassle! Glad to move on.