# I cannot install Zend Framework 2 Skeleton App via composer on wamp

Tags: php, zend-framework2, wamp

I want to install zend framework 2 Skeleton App

1. I did `php composer.phar self update`

Downloading completed: 100%

1. Then I did `php composer.phar install`

I get this error **[RuntimeException] You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https**.

I tried editing my php.ini and uncomment: **extension=php_openssl.dll**

I still get the same Error!

Thank you

---

**

### SOLUTION

**

Verify you are editing the correct php.ini file.

Reference: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1440

"WAMP uses different php.ini files in the CLI and for Apache. when you enable php_openssl through the WAMP UI, you enable it for Apache, not for the CLI. You need to modify C:\wamp\bin\php\php-X.Y.Z\php.ini to enable it for the CLI."

Answered By on another post by:  Duramba

Comment: you need to restart appache, if you havent done that do it and then try again

Comment: found the solution:

Verify you are editing the correct php.ini file.

Reference: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1440

"WAMP uses different php.ini files in the CLI and for Apache. when you enable php_openssl through the WAMP UI, you enable it for Apache, not for the CLI. You need to modify C:\wamp\bin\php\php-X.Y.Z\php.ini to enable it for the CLI."

share|edit
edited May 8 at 12:03

answered May 8 at 11:55

Duramba
7114

Comment: Ref; That other post by Duramba is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16440039/367456

Comment: possible duplicate of [You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291151/you-must-enable-the-openssl-extension-to-download-files-via-https)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify you are editing the correct php.ini file.

Reference: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1440

"WAMP uses different php.ini files in the CLI and for Apache. when you enable php_openssl through the WAMP UI, you enable it for Apache, not for the CLI. You need to modify C:\wamp\bin\php\php-X.Y.Z\php.ini to enable it for the CLI."

Answered On other post By:  Duramba

Thank you