# Installing zend skeleton application

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to install Zend Skeleton Application in my Wamp on windows 7 operating system. I have followed the following link on youtube to install the Zend http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41-qEbpG2XQ . Everything goes well, but at the end when I'm trying to install zend from composer.

```
php composer.phar
```

It is throwing an exception " You must enable openssl extension to download files vi https" . But I have enabled openssl from php.ini. What can I try next to install it successfully?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291151/you-must-enable-the-openssl-extension-to-download-files-via-https

Answer (score 1):

Please check your **wamp/bin/php/php{version}/php.ini** di and try to uncomment the line

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```