# Setting up Laravel 4 on Xampp

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to set up laravel 4 for the first time locally, and I get this error in the browser when I type in `http://localhost/testLaravel/public/`.

```
OpenSSL extension is required. 
Open: C:\xampp\htdocs\testLaravel\bootstrap\compiled.php 

       throw new DecryptException('MAC is invalid.');
   }
   return $payload;
}
protected function validMac(array $payload)
{
   if (!function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
       throw new \RuntimeException('OpenSSL extension is required.');
   }
   $bytes = (new SecureRandom())->nextBytes(16);
```

I think I am supposed to see "You have arrived" with Laravel logo.

My specifications are:

- `testLaravel` is my project name which is located `C:\xampp\htdocs\testLaravel`
- Laravel 4.2
- PHP/5.5.15
- Windows 8.1 x64
- Apache/2.4.4 (Win32)

I cross checked the OpenSSL to be enabled for PHP in `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

And for Apache in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

I am sure I do not have any other installation of PHP or Apache, but still I get the mentioned error.

**Update:** I remember once I updated my PHP version, by downloading newest PHP and copied all its files into XAMPP PHP's directory to update my PHP and it worked well so far. I doubt this is the problem, since I copied the the laravel project to a PC with original XAMPP installation and it worked. Also in `phpinfo()` I do not see OpenSSL section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291151/you-must-enable-the-openssl-extension-to-download-files-via-https)

Comment: @seeARMS I do not think it is duplicate of that, since they are talking about WAMP and possibility of wrong php.ini, that I have made clear is not my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, the problem was in my PHP installation. I followed s-sharma's instructions in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154762/upgrading-php-in-xampp-for-windows) and installed a new version of XAMPP to revert the changes, and the same installation of Laravel is working.