# Error "You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https"

Tags: php, openssl, xampp, composer-php

On running `composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"`, I get this error :

```
[RuntimeException]
You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https
```

I have this error when trying to install a package. I have seen many post on Stack Overflow. However, I did all what they do, and nothing works.

- Check my PHP CLI path. `php -i` said that is `C:\xampp\php\`
- Uncomment the `extension=php_openssl.dll` line in `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`.
- Check if `openssl` extension is in `C:\xampp\php\ext`

All this don't make work my Composer installation.

Thanks

Comment: Check which config file the CLI version is using with `php -i` (it's not always `php.ini`) and make sure you enabled the extension in that file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291151/you-must-enable-the-openssl-extension-to-download-files-via-https)