# How to forwards call from apache to nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, xampp

I am developing a web app that will upload the files on azure storage. For this I used

> Manage blobs with JavaScript v12 SDK in a browser>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/quickstart-blobs-javascript-browser

I work on Apache Xampp where I have a PHP file having button clicking on which should upload files. I want that when a user clicks on "upload" button then the above upload to blob storage gets appear on screen.

https://jsfiddle.net/mahajaved/p059vzka/3/
Hero is the demo, I want that in place of the div "uploaddiv", the html file appears and it works exactly the same as it is doing now.

HTML file is:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <button id="create-container-button">Create container</button>
    <button id="delete-container-button">Delete container</button>
    <button id="select-button">Select and upload files</button>
    <input type="file" id="file-input" multiple style="display: none;" />
    <button id="list-button">List files</button>
    <button id="delete-button">Delete selected files</button>
    <p><b>Status:</b></p>
    <p id="status" style="height:160px; width: 593px; overflow: scroll;" />
    <p><b>Files:</b></p>
    <select id="file-list" multiple style="height:222px; width: 593px; overflow: scroll;" />
</body>

<script src="./index.js"></script>

</html>
```

JavaScript file is:

```
// index.js
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
// Now do something interesting with BlobServiceClient

const createContainerButton = document.getElementById("create-container-button");
const deleteContainerButton = document.getElementById("delete-container-button");
const selectButton = document.getElementById("select-button");
const fileInput = document.getElementById("file-input");
const listButton = document.getElementById("list-button");
const deleteButton = document.getElementById("delete-button");
const status = document.getElementById("status");
const fileList = document.getElementById("file-list");

const reportStatus = message => {
    status.innerHTML += `${message}<br/>`;
    status.scrollTop = status.scrollHeight;
}

// Update <placeholder> with your Blob service SAS URL string to establish connection between our application and storage account
const blobSasUrl = "https://azurefileupload.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=2020-02-10&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=rwdlactfx&se=2021-06-05T16:49:19Z&st=2021-06-05T08:49:19Z&spr=https&sig=D%2FggJPtFqLm7s13ukQkmnvl3M24OKxPrUAvkyunOG%2Bc%3D";
// Create a new BlobServiceClient
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(blobSasUrl);

// Create a unique name for the container by 
// appending the current time to the file name
const containerName = "filecontainer";
const hostName = "https://azurefileupload.blob.core.windows.net";
// Get a container client from the BlobServiceClient
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

const createContainer = async () => {
    try {
        reportStatus(`Creating container "${containerName}"...`);
        await containerClient.create();
        reportStatus(`Done.`);
    } catch (error) {
        reportStatus(error.message);
    }
};

const deleteContainer = async () => {
    try {
        reportStatus(`Deleting container "${containerName}"...`);
        await containerClient.delete();
        reportStatus(`Done.`);
    } catch (error) {
        reportStatus(error.message);
    }
};

createContainerButton.addEventListener("click", createContainer);
deleteContainerButton.addEventListener("click", deleteContainer);

const listFiles = async () => {
    fileList.size = 0;
    fileList.innerHTML = "";
    try {
        reportStatus("Retrieving file list...");
        let iter = containerClient.listBlobsFlat();
        let blobItem = await iter.next();
        while (!blobItem.done) {
            fileList.size += 1;
            // fileList.innerHTML += `<option>${blobItem.value.name}</option>`;
            fileList.innerHTML += `<option>${blobService.getUrl(containerName,blobItem.value.name,null,hostName)}</option>`;
            blobItem = await iter.next();
        }
        if (fileList.size > 0) {
            reportStatus("Done.");
        } else {
            reportStatus("The container does not contain any files.");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        reportStatus(error.message);
    }
};

listButton.addEventListener("click", listFiles);

const uploadFiles = async () => {
    try {
        reportStatus("Uploading files...");
        const promises = [];
        for (const file of fileInput.files) {
            const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(file.name);
            promises.push(blockBlobClient.uploadBrowserData(file));
        }
        await Promise.all(promises);
        reportStatus("Done.");
        listFiles();
    }
    catch (error) {
            reportStatus(error.message);
    }
}

selectButton.addEventListener("click", () => fileInput.click());
fileInput.addEventListener("change", uploadFiles);

const deleteFiles = async () => {
    try {
        if (fileList.selectedOptions.length > 0) {
            reportStatus("Deleting files...");
            for (const option of fileList.selectedOptions) {
                await containerClient.deleteBlob(option.text);
            }
            reportStatus("Done.");
            listFiles();
        } else {
            reportStatus("No files selected.");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        reportStatus(error.message);
    }
};

deleteButton.addEventListener("click", deleteFiles);
```

Launch.json is:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            
            {
                "type": "pwa-chrome",
                "request": "launch",
                "name": "Launch chrome against localhost",
                "url": "http://localhost:1234/index.html",
                "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        ]
}
```

My question is little messed up, but I am having trouble explaining it.
I want files being uploaded to be saved on azure storage account. I found this method but have no idea how to integrate it in my application.

Comment: I am not an azure expert but from whatever you have explained and my understanding, all you want to do is upload files to azure... for that you can simply make use any of php lib that does upload work for you like 

https://github.com/kaijaeger/php-azure-blob-upload

You may need to use azure sdk for 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php

Comment: @RohitS I tried that but I could not find my way to it. No commands were running though I tried all possible solution

Comment: can you share what error you get?

Comment: I downloaded PHP and then I run the commands and get the error "openssl extension is missing". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070912/install-composer-fails-with-the-openssl-extension-is-missing-error I followed all options in here but couldn't resolve it

Comment: you can try, create a .php file and put `phpinfo()` inside it and open that file in a browser to check what all extensions are enabled for php.

or may be on terminal type php -i to check enabled extesions.

you will need to enable the missing extension as one reported open ssl

check this link
https://faq.miniorange.com/knowledgebase/enable-php-openssl-extension/

Comment: Now I am wondering why you need nodjs looking at the title of your question? also if this is the issue then its not related to nodejs or php or how to redirect input from a to be but, your setup. please consider restructuring your question if any.

Comment: What you have told, I have done that but of no use. And now I have shown code in question which uses nodejs which is doing what I want and now I need that part in my application

Comment: show me what you have tried ? did you enabled open SSL or any other extension required? if you want to stick with nodejs only then use azure nodesdk
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node

Comment: @RohitS Now that openssl is working, when I run php composer.phar install in terminal of vscode it is saying: PHP Warning:  Module "openssl" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module "openssl" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Could not open input file: composer.phar