# How to install Symfony 2.6 with wamp server in windows 8 successfully?

Tags: php, symfony, windows-8, wampserver

I am new to web development and I tried to install Symfony to my Laptop.. I have already installed fallowing softwares.

Windows 8 ( 64x )

wamp Server 2.4 (includes php5.4.12 & mysql5.6.12)

MySql Server 5.6 (This is not useless but I have installed)

I added **C:\wamp\bin** to **path** in **System Variable**

When I was trying to install Symfony I had to download **Composer** first So I downloaded **Composer-Setup.exe** from [here](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

Then I run the wamp Server and went to PHP Extensions then Enabled **php_curl**  and **php_openssl** also.

I did run **Composer-Setup.exe** file and selected **Do not install shell menus** and continued.

set ***C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.exe*** as the path to **php.exe** file

Finally I got following **Composer Download error** message

```
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl
```

Have I done wrong steps ? How can I solve this issue. Please help me to solve this and install Symfony 2.6 with wamp server 2.4 in Windows 8.

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062055/composer-warning-openssl-extension-is-missing-how-to-enable-in-wamp
maybe its the solution for you

Comment: I would uninstall the seperate MySQL 5.6 as it will only cause confusion later. In fact if you installed it using an .msi install that is the version of MySQL that is probably being started as it is probably set to start automatically on boot. You should also remove the PATH setting as it is of no use as there is nothing in the `c:\wamp\bin` folder to execute anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This method does not use the composer but is equally effective

1. First ensure that PHP is available to your Path environment/system variable, if not add it.
2. Once you have added php to your environment variable restart your computer and open cmd and cd to your web root directory (project directory)
3. In cmd run the following:

   `$php -r "readfile('https://symfony.com/installer');" >` `symfony`

This will download a file named `symfony` into your project directory (i.e. directory from where cmd is run)

4. Install the latest version of symfony as follows:

   `$php` `symfony new` `my_project_name`

OR

5. Install/use the most recent version in a specific branch say 2.8

   `$php` `symfony new my_project_name 2.8`

OR

6. Install/use specific version version within a specific branch

   `$php symfony new` `my_project_name 2.8.3`

Note: steps 4, 5, or 6 will take some time, depending on your Internet speed to download Symfony

Answer (score -2):

Is there a specific reason you want to install a WAMP stack? In my experience it's much easier and flexible to use Vagrant to provision a virtual machine with the right specs

1. Portable: just run vagrant up on another machine, wait a few minutes, and you're done
2. Allows you to keep the configuration of your developer's machines and the target server the same
3. Fixing a broken package just requires you to run vagrant up --provision later
4. Many packages like composer are written more with *Unix-systems in mind and will be easier to maintain and install.

Simply put, configuring an entire server directly on your machine is tedious work and isn't longer necessary. The [Vaprobash](https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash) project is a good example of how to get started