# how to disable "unable to load php_pdo_mssql.dll" error

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Every time I start *Apache* with php **5.4.16** one error display on manitor

**php startup: unable to load dynamic library .../php5.4.16/ext/php_pdo_mssql.dll - the specific module could not be found**

but I don't want to use it and there isn't this file in the directory. In **php.ini** I comment the php_pdo_mssql.dll

```
;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
```

I am using *apache 2.4.4* and *window 8*

**UPDATE** solved ;)

WAMP uses different php.ini files in the CLI and for Apache. when you enable php_openssl through the WAMP UI, you enable it for Apache, not for the CLI. You need to modify C:\wamp\bin\php\php-5.x.x\php.ini to enable it for the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the semi-colon to load the file, and if you don't have that extension in your ext folder, you can download it. Sorry but I forgot where to download a dll file, just please google it.Thank you. Its ok if you don't want to use that extension,you just have to do it to just to avoid the error.Hope this helps.

Comment: it is not good approach , I find the answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14265815/4360116)