# Composer Download error - Certificate verify failed

Tags: php, symfony, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to install Symfony2 on my laptop (win7). I'm following a tutorial who's saying that I need to install the composer. I launched the Windows installer and all was good until this : [here is the screnshot of the errors I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1bKd.png)

- I'm using wamp with php 5.5.12 and Apache 2.4.9
- I tried to do it with the command line but it didn't work

(Sorry for my english, I'm a swiss student)

Help me please :)

Comment: The first part of the error sorry : http://hpics.li/98a8a98

Comment: http://hpics.li/98a8a98 doesn't work.

Comment: http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=221685Capture.png this one should work, sorry ! @LeśnyRumcajs :)

Comment: First option is that the installer can't get the certificate - whether it is because the server doesn't show any, or the installer is behind some proxy - check this please.
The second option is that the verification itself fails, in that case you have to check what CAs is the installer using, or send a message to Composer devs - maybe their certificate expired and they're not aware of it.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062055/composer-warning-openssl-extension-is-missing-how-to-enable-in-wamp