# Composer Warning: openssl extension is missing. How to enable in Denwer

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php

I try install Composer and it returns error: **The openssl extension is missing. The recommended option is to enable the extension in your php.ini.** 
In php.ini string "**extension=php_openssl.dll**" is not commented out.
I use Denwer. 
How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Denwer is obsolete. Use XAMPP, WampServer, Open Server, etc. And ... ru.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1):

According with this Question: [Composer Warning: openssl extension is missing. How to enable in WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062055/composer-warning-openssl-extension-is-missing-how-to-enable-in-wamp) WAMP (like Denwer) uses different php.ini for Apache and for CLI (PHP running in terminal, like **composer**).

As long I can see the php.ini file in Denwer is locate in "C:\WebServers\usr\local\php5\php.ini" and by default line "extension=php_openssl.dll" is commented (;), even uncommenting it PHP doesn't load OpenSSL.

In this site: http://hardmandev.com/article/nastroyka-openssl-dlya-denwer/ (In Russian) they suggest a way to make Openssl works on Denwer. According the feedback in the commentaries, this trick works.

I hope this can help you.